# Q>javascript regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var filter1 = /^\d{3}+[\-]+[A-Za-z1-9]{2}+[\-]+\d{3}+[A-Z]{2}+$/ ;
```

i want to get this pattern NNN-xx-NNNLL

N here means any numeral from 0 to 9 while x means alphanumeric characters except zero (0) and underscore (_) and L means a capital alphabet letter from A through Z.

help please. my pattern is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plus sign means one or more occurencies of the preceedig element. You use it wrongly here.
Also a dash is a litteral outside the brackets, and you don't need them.

```
var filter1 = /^\d{3}-[_A-Za-z1-9]{2}-\d{3}[A-Z]{2}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using **+** wrong in your expression. In regular expressions, plus means *at least one of the preceding expression*. It is not, however, used as a concentrator. Your expression should work fine if you just remove all occurences of **+**.

```
var filter1 = /^\d{3}[\-][A-Za-z1-9_]{2}[\-]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:`^\d{3}-[A-Z1-9a-z]{2}-\d{3}[A-Z]{2}$`?